# Laravel Request validation for 4 digits which is also not requried parameter

Tags: laravel, validation

I want to validate a pin code that is just for 4 digits and it should not be required.
means pin code is only 4 digits. like 1234, 8675,  or if the user does not enter any digits to Pincode input type let the user submit the form. I want to give the database's default value 1111 if the user doesn't enter the pin code.

Comment: Which part of this are you struggling with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: validation for 4 digits

Comment: 'pin_code' => 'sometimes|max:4',     but it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can validate the request (or use a form request) that allows `pin` to be `null` otherwise validates it is a 4 digit number. You can then get the `pin` from the input or fallback to the default value of `1111.`

```php
$request->validate([
    'pin' => ['nullable', 'numeric', 'digits:4'],
]);

$pin = $request->input('pin', '1111');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
     
            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [                
                'pin' => ['numeric' , 'min:4', 'max:4']         
            ]);
            
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                 $pin = 1111;
            }           
            
            if ($validator->validated()) 
            {   
                $pin = $request->pin;   
            }
```